# Extract subset of linestring based on distance

Tags: qgis, vector

I have two datasets, one containing a single linestring representing paths, one with several points representing hubs intersecting the linestring (or: one with roads, one with houses sitting "on" the road). I want to extract the exact distance along the linestring within a certain distance from the points.

Extract within distance returns the whole linestring. Segmentizing the linestring into multiple parts (ie. by splitting at nodes) yields only an approximate result, as the segments still have some length.
I could create points along lines, and segmentize the linestring by those points, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...found the Service Area function, which does the trick

More detailed: One can use the "Service Area (From Layer) function, where the network is the linestring, path to calculate "shortest", vector layer with start points the start points and the travel cost the distance along the linestring

Comment: Future readers will likely appreciate a more detailed answer!

Comment: More detailed: One can use the "Service Area (From Layer) function, where the network is the linestring, path to calculate "shortest", vector layer with start points the start points and the travel cost the distance along the linestring.

Comment: Add this to the answer, not as a comment.